# How to declare a large number of images

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have to declare a large number of images (like 350 images).
Now I'm declaring the images like that:

```
var largeImages: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "G_0.png")!, 
    UIImage(named: "G_1.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "G_2.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "G_3.png")!]
```

How to declare a large number of images?

Comment: Are they all copies of the same image as you've shown here, or do the images have different names? Are the names computed (`_1`, `_2`, etc.), or all completely unique?

Comment: Unless you _really_ need them allocated all at one, you could just store the image names and create a function to return a new image when you need it...

Comment: Why don't use a loop? Do you have the memory available for these 350 images? I'd create a subclass that is instanicaetd with he name (or url to) and that loads it dynamically upon request and that provides a method to free the image from memory in case of memory warnings received.

Comment: they have different number var largeImages: '[UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "G_0.png")!, 
    UIImage(named: "G_1.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "G_2.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "G_3.png")!]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var largeImages = [UIImage]()
for index in 0...100 {
  largeImages.append(UIImage(named: "G_\(index).png")!)
}
```

although i do not think you need the ".png" extension. you can try leaving it out! and - as the other guys stated in their comments - you should really think about instantiating the images as needed...

Comment: thank you ;), How to do the similar thing with a 365 URL?

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you don't. You need to understand that one cannot allocate more than just a few UIImage objects at the same time. Attempting to allocate many (more than say 20) UIImage objects is likely going to crash your app because you will run out of memory. If you are trying to implement video/animations then make use of an existing animation library instead of just trying to roll your own implementation of Quicktime.